# Where to encash American check in Australia?

Tags: usa, australia, currency

Where/How can I encash a US Treasury check in Australia ? 
Of course, for the least fee.

Comment: I see there is a close vote for this question. I personally think it's OK but explaining how it is relevant to expatriates could perhaps be useful.

Comment: Is this different from any other kind of US cheque? Also, I wonder if Money.SE mightn't be a better home for this?

Comment: I am posting it in the expatriates site because I hope to find more than one person who moved away from America and has received tax returns in a check. And what are the ways one goes about encashing them. I checked with my local bank and they said they have never dealt with this before but looked up a few books and said "you can get your money in 20 weeks mate" - which is a lot of time

Comment: @Gagravarr: At least within the US, Treasury checks are handled specially; there are different rules for depositing and clearing them (including shorter hold periods).  I suspect it probably won't make a difference in this case, but it is certainly worth mentioning.

Comment: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/22535/how-can-i-deposit-usd-money-in-my-australian-checking-account-while-incurring-as

Answer (score 2):

I've deposited Treasury (tax refund) checks twice in Melbourne, at the bank (nab). Once they insisted in locking it up for three months, and once I got the money in a few days. Same bank, same branch, similar amount. No idea why but didn't want to ask too many questions :)

The bank takes a fee of about $15 AUD - I don't know if you can get a better deal elsewhere.